# How to create a build file or sh file in Python

Tags: python, build

```
# Python3 code to check if a given
# number is perfect or not
 
# Returns true if n is perfect
def isPerfect( n ):
     
    # To store sum of divisors
    sum = 1
     
    # Find all divisors and add them
    i = 2
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            sum = sum + i + n/i
        i += 1
     
    # If sum of divisors is equal to
    # n, then n is a perfect number
     
    return (True if sum == n and n!=1 else False)
 
# Driver program
print("Below are all perfect numbers till 10000")
n = 2
for n in range (10000):
    if isPerfect (n):
        print(n , " is a perfect number")
         
# This code is contributed by "Sharad_Bhardwaj".
```

Hi, I'm trying to figure to how to create a build file or sh file in order to compile and run the code when I send it to someone else. This is just an example if I have a code like this, how could I create a build file or sh file so that will compile and run the code automatically?

Comment: You shouldn't use python for that, use a Makefile.

Comment: You used tag `python` and posted piece of code which definitely is not `python`, please explain that discrepancy